# URL can't be converted to string - Graph API response value

Tags: spfx, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-graph

The following gets the URL but can't convert it to string. respJSON.mySite has the value but not mySiteFullURL. I tried multiple approaches like tostring(), etc. but still can't get the URL as string.

```
protected _readMySite():string {
let mySiteFullURL : string;
this.context.graphHttpClient.get(`v1.0/me?$select=mySite`, GraphHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  } else {
    console.warn(response.statusText);
  }
}).then((respJSON:any) => {
  console.log('respJSON.mySite ' + respJSON.mySite);
  mySiteFullURL = respJSON.mySite;
});
console.log('mySiteFullURL '+mySiteFullURL);
return mySiteFullURL;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a Promise which will give you the value. You are currently returning a string which will undefined since your method will not wait for the ajax call to be completed.

Modify your code as below:

```
protected _readMySite(): Promise<any> {
let mySiteFullURL: string;
    return this.context.graphHttpClient.get(`v1.0/me?$select=mySite`, GraphHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        console.warn(response.statusText);
      }
    }).then((respJSON: any) => {
      console.log('respJSON.mySite ' + respJSON.mySite);
      mySiteFullURL = respJSON.mySite;
      return mySiteFullURL;
});
```

Usage:

```
var myPersonalsite = this._readMySite();
myPersonalsite.then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```